# Using Pandas merge to perform lookup

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have looked up on the site and saw numerous answers and tried to modify them to do what I want to do but for some reason I am not getting the result.

I have two dataframes, one with millions of rows called Big_df with 10 columns and one with 1000 rows with 6 columns called Small_df.

`Small_df` has column 'Print_ID' and `Big_df` has 'Job_ID' that are in common to the dataframes.  I need to retrieve column 'Status' from `Big_df` and add it to the `Small_df`.  This is the code:

```py
NewSmall_df = pd.merge(Small_df, Big_df, left_on = 'Print_ID', right_on ='Job_ID')
```

I get a result of 2000+ rows which is not correct as `Small_df` has 1000 rows and the maximum would be 1000 or less depending if there is a `NaN` in one of the IDs.  I have looked at the answers for all the similar type questions on Stackoverflow and elsewhere, I should be getting the result that I am looking for.

The result that I am looking for is to have an extra column added to `small_df` that has the 'Status' from `Big_df` matched by the Print_ID & Job_ID.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Below is a sample data:

Small_df:
[Smal_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scEZf.png)

Big_df:
[Big_df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrCvX.png)

Result_df:
[Result_df after matching Print_ID and Job_ID to return Status as the last column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeoZO.png)

Comment: have you tried with `how='left'`?

Comment: I tried how='left' , It gives me an even higher row count, close to 3000

Comment: that makes no sense, without sample data it's hard to pinpoint the error. Good luck

Comment: Yuca - I noticed there were duplicates in my big_df dataframe.  Once I used drop_dulicates on the dataframes, and then do what you suggested by adding how = 'left' worked.  Thanks.